# Push multiple files with GitHub tree API using Java

Tags: java, github-api, git-push

I was trying to push multiple files at single instance, so by searching I got to know that we have to:

- create the blobs for each of the files, then
- add 'sha' of the blob to tree object, then
- create a tree and finally
- commit that tree.

I'm trying to replicate the same using java code but struggling a lot:
kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can take inspiration from JGit mentioned in "[Embedding Git in your Applications - JGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit)" of the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

> If you want to use Git from within a Java program, there is a fully featured Git library called JGit.
>
> JGit is a relatively full-featured implementation of Git written natively in Java, and is widely used in the Java community.
> The JGit project is under the Eclipse umbrella, and its home can be found at https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/.

You can find a mirror of the repository in [`github.com/eclipse/jgit`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), where:

- a [`org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/Commit.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/1c6bd377ffd39a9473a54012ba8f515e55ee1709/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/src/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/Commit.java#L62-L91) takes all the commit possible options, and then call:
- a [`org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/1c6bd377ffd39a9473a54012ba8f515e55ee1709/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.java#L224-L248), which does create the tree.

That is (extract):

```java
try (ObjectInserter odi = repo.newObjectInserter()) {
    if (!only.isEmpty())
        index = createTemporaryIndex(headId, index, rw);

    // Write the index as tree to the object database. This may
    // fail for example when the index contains unmerged paths
    // (unresolved conflicts)
    ObjectId indexTreeId = index.writeTree(odi);

    if (insertChangeId)
        insertChangeId(indexTreeId);

    checkIfEmpty(rw, headId, indexTreeId);

    // Create a Commit object, populate it and write it
    CommitBuilder commit = new CommitBuilder();
    commit.setCommitter(committer);
    commit.setAuthor(author);
    commit.setMessage(message);
    commit.setParentIds(parents);
    commit.setTreeId(indexTreeId);

    if (signCommit.booleanValue()) {
        sign(commit);
    }
    ...
}
```